# Windows UWP app on RPi 3 internet connection state mistification

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10-universal, iot

I want to know the current internet state on my RPi using windows IoT Core. To get the internet state I am using this method:

```
public static bool GetInternetConnectionState()
{
    var connection = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
    var internet = connection?.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel();
    return internet == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess;
}
```

When I unplug the internet cable from router, my handler recognize the network has changed but this method still returns internet access true although internet is not available but when I remove the cable from RPi it works great. Does anybody know why is this happening?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. What's your iot core version?

Comment: My OS version is v.10.0.15063.0

Comment: I test on 15063 but it has no such issue.

Comment: Yeah it's strange but it's true. The handler recognize the change but this method returns internet access. I use mikrotik router